# SQL query Union All

Tags: sql, oracle, jpa

I am combining around 7 different tables(requirement) from OracleDB by forming an sql query with Union all condition. Currently I have included it as a native query in JPA. I see it is taking too much time. Records size increases day by day. But I see more time taken while executing from java side. So please let me  know is there a way I can optimize the SQL query performance.

```
  Select distinct e.name, e.project, e.marks, e.address from table1 where e.date > sysdate
union all

 Select distinct m.name, m.project, m.marks, m.address from table2 where m.date > sysdate

etc for other tables
```

Comment: So you're firing the query above against the Oracle database, and then you fetch all rows into a Java Persistence API framework. Try to change your select into a `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE dropme AS SELECT .. .UNION SELECT .... etc.`, and time that execution. This gives you a hint on how much Oracle is working. For the Java side: How many rows to you fetch in one call? i.e, how big is your rowset? Increase it, and it might help you

Comment: At present from one table I have seen 5000 records which will increase as a job runs daily that feeds these records into our DB.

Comment: How many rows will be returned with the filter you use, in each table? that determines the rows you need to fetch from the database. If your Java application has a bad rowset - the worst being 1, then, for 5000 rows, you will have 5000 loopbacks. If your loopback time is 0.2 seconds, only fetching the rows will take 16 minutes 40 seconds ...

Comment: It depends daily basis. Approximately combining all tables it might be come upto 10,000 records.

Comment: Then, again, do the `CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT ...` as I said before, measure the time it takes that way. The difference in time is all due to the client  part: Network speed, inefficient programming on the Java side. If it's not on the database side, I'm the wrong one to try to help you ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When fetching records using JPA, it generates additional classes around your entities necessary to manage its state(hence 'persistency management'). If the resultset is only used for reading content, you can define DTO classes and mark them as Readonly (how to do this depends on the JPA framework you use). This reduces the overhead of JPA and will increase performance.